# Asterisk Digest Authentication for SIP INVITE gives "user mismatch" error

Tags: asterisk, sip, digest-authentication

I am building a basic SIP UA. I am sending the following INVITE, as seen in Asterisk console (only headers relevant to authentication are shown):

```
INVITE sip:104@192.168.1.92 SIP/2.0
From: "110"<sip:110@192.168.1.92>;tag=80859256
To: <sip:104@192.168.1.92>
Call-ID: 80859256
CSeq: 80859256 INVITE
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.1.92:6000;branch=z9hG4bK-80859256
Contact: <sip:110@192.168.1.92>
```

In response, I get the following challenge:

```
 SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized
 Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.1.92:6000;branch=z9hG4bK-   80859256;received=127.0.0.1
 From: "110"<sip:110@192.168.1.92>;tag=80859256
 To: <sip:104@192.168.1.92>;tag=as25af7f49
 Call-ID: 80859256
 CSeq: 80859256 INVITE
 Server: Asterisk PBX 13.7.2
 Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE
 Supported: replaces, timer
 WWW-Authenticate: Digest algorithm=MD5, realm="asterisk", nonce="20e95772"
 Content-Length: 0
```

I reply with the following:

```
 ACK sip:104@192.168.1.92 SIP/2.0
 From: "110"<sip:110@192.168.1.92>;tag=80859256
 To: <sip:104@192.168.1.92>;tag=as25af7f49
 Call-ID: 80859256
 CSeq: 80859256 ACK
 Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.1.92:6000;rport;branch=z9hG4bK-80859256
 Contact: <sip:110@192.168.1.92>
 Content-Length: 0


 INVITE sip:104@192.168.1.92 SIP/2.0
 From: "110"<sip:110@192.168.1.92>;tag=80859256
 To: <sip:104@192.168.1.92>
 Call-ID: 80859256
 CSeq: 80859257 INVITE
 Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.1.92:6000;rport;branch=z9hG4bK-80859257
 Max-Forwards:5
 Allow: REGISTER, INVITE, ACK, BYE, REFER, NOTIFY, CANCEL, INFO, OPTIONS, PRACK, SUBSCRIBE
 Contact: <sip:110@192.168.1.92>
 Authorization: Digest
 username="110",realm="asterisk", nonce="20e95772",uri="sip:104@192.168.1.92",response="ed2de012b2255e85ddb0ee724b9a3ffd"
 Session-Expires: 1800
 Min-SE: 90
 Content-Type: application/sdp
```

I have not included above the actual SDP sent with the invites. The password for extension  110 is 110 as defined in sip.conf.

QUESTION:
I am getting this error:

```
 WARNING...: chan_sip.c:16702 check_auth: username mismatch, have <110>, digest has <>
 NOTICE...: chan_sip.c:25603 handle_request_invite: Failed to authenticate device "110"<sip:110@192.168.1.92>;tag=76981187
```

This is followed by a "SIP/2.0 403 Forbidden" message.

I do not believe that my digest calculation as sent in the second INVITE is wrong.

What needs to be changed? I have spent a lot of time in debugging this... 
Any help would be HIGHLY appreciated.

Comment: Is there a CR+LF in your actual response between "Authorization: Digest" and "username=...", or is this just being added in the debug output in the console? If so, you need to start the new line with whitespace or it will not be considered a continuation of the Authorization header field, i.e. the Authorization field would not contain a username

Comment: @snowcloned Thanks a LOT. That was it. I did not realize that I was inserting a CR+LF after "Digest" until you pointed it out. I just thought it was a wrapped-around display in the console. Changed that and it works. Can you provide this as an answer and I will be VERY happy to accept it because it is indeed an answer not just a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The username in the response is being parsed by Asterisk as empty because the Authorization header field ends after the CR+LF between the words "Digest" and "username". In order for a header field to be continued on a new line, the line needs to start with whitespace; from [RFC3261](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3261.txt):

```
Header fields can be extended over multiple lines by preceding each extra line with at least
one SP or horizontal tab (HT).  The line break and the whitespace at the beginning of the
next line are treated as a single SP character.
```

Either removing the CR+LF, or inserting whitespace at the beginning of the new line should correct the problem.